# How should we distinguish blog posts in the Twitter feed?

Tags: discussion, blog, twitter

Should we add a hashtag, or other particular prefix/suffix to the blog tweets, to distinguish them from the regular question tweets?  If so, what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't have to be a hashtag.  What about:

```
Blog: <title>
```

Edit:  I've modified the Twitter settings, so all blog tweets should now be in this format.

Comment: I think using a prefix like that reduces the impact of the title (which was presumably designed to be attention-getting by itself).  A #blog hashtag, at the end as usual, avoids that problem and seems designed for representing metadata, and should make it easier and clearer for folks to classify entries.

Answer (score 3):

There already exists both  [#security](https://twitter.com/#!/search/#security) and [#infosec](https://twitter.com/#!/search?q=%23InfoSec) hashtags. Looking at the posts tagged with each, either could work, though #infosec might be better grouping for what we want.

I don't know how to tell which one has more followers, but if that information is available it should guide the choice.

Comment: I'm not sure why this one has a couple down-votes, but I actually like it because it gets exposure for our content in areas where non-SE users might take notice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that most tweets from https://twitter.com/#!/StackSecurity link to new qustions, and have a hashtag set based on the tag of the question.  The tweets about blog entries have no tag at all.

I think just #blog is good.  I like the sound of #SecSEblog, but I think for this case we don't want a unique hashtag.  After all the sender is already sort of a brand combining StackExchange and Security.  We want a hashtag that is helpful and ties us in to other stuff in the blog world.  So #blog seems to fit the bill.