# Should we add #infosec to our Twitter bot's posts, for publicity?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, twitter

This idea is spawned from @ScottPack's post in the thread about distinguishing blog posts in Twitter:

[How should we distinguish blog posts in the Twitter feed?](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/397/how-should-we-distinguish-blog-posts-in-the-twitter-feed/403#403)

I think it could bring a bit of publicity (and, hopefully, more traffic - and, consequently, more users) to the site if we added the #infosec hashtag - one which is more widely used *outside* of our little circle, but still by our target audience - to some (or all) of our tweets.

This question actually breaks down into a few, that will need to be answered before we actually put in a request to SEI:

1. Should this be done at all?
2. If so, is #infosec really the best tag to use, or is there another that might be a better fit and/or gain us more exposure within the target audience?
3. Where should the chosen tag be used - on blog tweets only, question tweets only, or both?

Comment: What is our target audience? Is the purpose of a blog tweet different from the purpose of a question tweet?

Comment: I think our blogs may appeal to a wider audience than our questions, but generally the target is the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Yes
2. #infosec works for me
3. Both

:-)

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff - PING!

Answer (score 1):

I mark my tweets with #infosec when I send out a question regarding this topic.