# Should the Twitter bot be tweeting Meta questions?

Tags: support, twitter

I'm thinking no, but here's one nonetheless:

https://twitter.com/StackSecurity/status/101115852664995840

---

And, as long as we're talking about the Twitter bot, when can we get this implemented?

[Should we add #infosec to our Twitter bot's posts, for publicity?](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/should-we-add-infosec-to-our-twitter-bots-posts-for-publicity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the twitter bot will do a few new things now:

[Would allowing moderators to update their Stack Exchange sites' Twitter accounts improve visibility and offer more value?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92235/would-allowing-moderators-to-update-their-stack-exchange-sites-twitter-accounts/101340#101340)

Refer to that meta post for the specifics.

Comment: Good to know.  Could we mark the Meta questions in the tweets, with a prefix of "Meta: " like is being done for the "Great Answer: " type posts?

Comment: they are already tagged #discussion which is pretty clear IMO

Answer (score 2):

Just saw the bot saying : "hey new design has been launched".

So it is interesting to have the meta active question in newlsetter, but the score on meta seems to reach the Twitter publish threshold too slowly to be interesting. Anyway, meta question won't bring more audience. At best this feed serves as intimate tracking of the site. We don't want to tell the earth about it. Maybe encourage participation, but there are other ways for this.